# Unreal Engine: Take 2 screenshots during same tick (or equivalent)

Tags: module, screenshot, texture2d, unreal-engine5

I am working on an UE5 module that takes a high resolution and regular resolution screenshots each tick. I currently have a code that works for one screenshot with a given `ResolutionWidth` and `ResolutionHeight`. It takes `AmountOfPicturesToTake` screenshots with a delta of `ScreenshotIntervalSeconds` seconds between each screenshot:

```cpp
void AScreenShotUtility::Tick(float DeltaTime)
{
    Super::Tick(DeltaTime);
    if (numberOfShots >= AmountOfPicturesToTake)
    {
        return;
    }

    // Take High res screenshot
    CurrentTimeWithRespectToInterval -= DeltaTime;
    if (CurrentTimeWithRespectToInterval <= 0.0f)
    {
        ++numberOfShots;
        GIsHighResScreenshot = true;
        GScreenshotResolutionX = ResolutionWidth;
        GScreenshotResolutionY = ResolutionHeight;
        FScreenshotRequest::RequestScreenshot(true);
        CurrentTimeWithRespectToInterval = ScreenshotIntervalSeconds;
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to take two screenshots of the **exact** same frame at two resolutions. I tried using `RenderTargets` and creating textures from it, but Textures only support base of 2 numbers for dimensions.

Is there a way I can take two screenshots at each tick in the same module instance, or would I need to create two instances that consider a different resolution? If I do so, am I insured that the captured frames will be the exact same ones?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use two threads.

You can do it by using `std::thread`.